# Augmentation ideal is finitely generated if and only if $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $A \subset k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be a subalgebra, which is also a graded subspace $A = \oplus_{i \ge 0} A_i$. One can write $A = A_0 \oplus A_{> 0}$ where we have $A_0 = k^0[x_1, \dots, x_n] = k$ and $A_{> 0} := \oplus_{i \ge 1} A_i$ is a graded ideal of $A$, known as the augmentation ideal.

My question is, is it necessary the case that the ideal $A_{> 0}$ is finitely generated (as an $A$-module) if and only if $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra?

Comment: The algebra $A$ is finitely generated over $k$ if and only if it is finitely generated by elements in the augmentation ideal: if you have a list of generators $\{x_i\}$ then you can ``translate'' them to a list of generators $\{x_i-a_i\}$ in the augmentation ideal. Now if $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra then by an easy grading argument the same finite set of generators will generate the ideal. If the ideal is finitely generated, then the same generators will generate $A$ as an algebra.

Comment: To clarify Ehud's comment, the $x_i$ he lists in his comment are not the polynomial generators of the ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, but rather are some set of generators for $A$ as a $k$-algebra. Then, if $\varepsilon : A \rightarrow k$ denotes the augmentation map, $a_i = \varepsilon(x_i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This amounts to an exercise, applying what are perhaps the first few theorems you encounter in the context of noetherian rings. Moreover, the assumption that $A$ is a graded subring of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is stronger than necessary. It is enough to assume that $k$ is a commutative noetherian ring and that $A$ is a commutative augmented $k$-algebra (but even these assumptions are stronger than necessary).

I will write $A_+$ for the augmentation ideal of $k$. For one direction of the equivalence, if you know that $A_+$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module, then it follows more or less immediately that $A$ is generated as a $k$-algebra by your set of $A$-module generators for $A_+$ together with $1$.

For the other direction, assume that $A$ is finitely-generated as a $k$-algebra, so that $A$ is a quotient of a polynomial algebra of the form $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Then it is a consequence of Hilbert's Basis Theorem that $A$ is a noetherian ring. Now $A_+$ is an $A$-submodule of the left $A$-module $A$, so $A_+$ must be a noetherian $A$-module. Then by one of the first theorems you encounter for noetherian rings, $A_+$ must be finitely-generated as a left $A$-module.

**Edit:** As Eric pointed out in the comments, I made a careless error in the second paragraph of my answer. As he says, if you take $A$ to be the power series ring $k[[x]]$, then $A_+$ is generated as a left $A$-module by $\{x\}$, but the set $\{x,1\}$ does not generate $k[[x]]$ as an algebra (it generates only the subring $k[x]$). On the other hand, if you assume that $A$ is a positively graded algebra, then the inductive argument indicated by Todd in his comment shows that $A$ is generated as a $k$-algebra by the generating set for $A_+$ together with $1$.

Comment: It's not true that generators of $A_+$ as an ideal will automatically generate $A$ as an algebra.  For instance, consider $A=k[[x]]$.  The argument indicated in Ehud's comment uses induction on degree and is specific to the hypotheses stated in the question.

Comment: Could you please give more details why $A$ is algebra-generated by the module generators of $A_+$ in case $A$ is just suppossed to be augmented. I tried the following: Let $A_+=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and let $x \in A$. Then $x-\varepsilon(x) \in A_+$, so there are $a_i\in A$ s.t. $x-\varepsilon(x)=\sum_i a_ix_i$. Again write $a_j - \varepsilon(a_j)=\sum_i b_ix_i$ with $b_i \in A$. In the (positively) graded case this process stops because $\deg(b_j) < \deg(a_i)< \deg(x)$. But how to conclude in the non-graded case ?